# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory in nextjs for importing svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js

i want to import svg to my nextjs website.. but there is always showing an error message like

`error - uncaughtException: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Farha\Documents\Project\koneksi group\konekita-nextjs\.next\cache\images\FjvaNRy8j3Q2B5QVEFbngFxxzA-q4rIlyUah4YXnX7E=\0.1646376001271.TSiJgHKD29AAycfHNAnUb+fg3qfvj+OBRBcaaXEA0O8=.svg'`

whats wrong with my svg ? anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you share the code where you're using the SVG?

Comment: yes, i only import the svg just like this 
import overview from "./../../../../public/assets/icon/overview.svg";

Comment: and call them with image component from nextjs.. <Image src={overview} width={24} height={24}/>